# XPath select links but not images

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath, web-crawler

I am working on a WebCrawler. This web crawler get´s all the links from a Google search depending on a given search word.

My WebCrawler successfully list´s all the links.
**Here is the problem:** I dont want the WebCrawler to list the links for Google images.

I select the nodes using XPath.
Here is my XPath for the link selection:

```
//a[@href]
```

-- this works perfectly.

And here is my selection for links and not images:

```
/a[@href] | //*[not(self::g-img)]]
```

-- this does not work.

Google uses `<g-img...>...</g-img>` to mark the images.

I get the following `XPath Exception` error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: '//a[@href] | //*[not(self::g-img)]]' is an invalid Token.
```

Here is my C# Code for a button click:

```
private void urlButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            itemsListBox.Items.Clear();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            byte[] resultsBuffer = new byte[8192];

            string searchResults = "http://google.com/search?q=" + keyWordTextBox.Text.Trim() + "&num=" + numTextBox.Text;

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(searchResults);
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

            Stream rStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

            string tempString = null;
            int count = 0;

            do
            {
                count = rStream.Read(resultsBuffer, 0, resultsBuffer.Length);
                if (count != 0)
                {
                    tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(resultsBuffer, 0, count);
                    sb.Append(tempString);
                }
            }

            while (count > 0);
            string sbString = sb.ToString();

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            html.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
            html.LoadHtml(sbString);

            HtmlNode doc = html.DocumentNode;

            string nodeSelection = "//a[@href] | //*[not(self::g-img)]]";

            // TODO insert correct xpath
            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.SelectNodes(nodeSelection))
            {
                string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);

                if (!hrefValue.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("GOOGLE") && hrefValue.ToString().Contains("/url?q=") && (hrefValue.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("HTTP://") || hrefValue.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("HTTPS://")))
                {
                    int index = hrefValue.IndexOf("&");

                    if (index > 0)
                    {
                        hrefValue = hrefValue.Substring(0, index);
                        itemsListBox.Items.Add(hrefValue.Replace("/url?q=", ""));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I use the `HtmlAgilityPack`. It is very usefull in this case. I try to fix this for quite a while now and I was not able to find any help on stackoverflow or on google.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra `]` in your xpath.

This:

```
//a[@href] | //*[not(self::g-img)]]
```

Should be:

```
//a[@href] | //*[not(self::g-img)]
```

Even though that is now syntactically correct, I don't think it would select what you want. It would select a union of all `a` elements with an href attribute and all elements that aren't named `g-img`.

Try this instead:

```
//*[@href and not(self::g-img)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath Working 100% with examples :

```
//a[@href and not(child::g-img)]
```

Examples:

1 Test Live with http://xpather.com/G3DDdVQq

```
//a[@href and not(child::g-img)]
```

2 Test Live with http://xpather.com/DjO1hGsm

```
//a[@href and (child::g-img)]
```